# Unwrap torso part creates a messed up UV map

Tags: uv

I extracted a part of a body to buid some clothing from (Unity UMA).
The original body was perfectly UV'd.
Since I want to cover a part of the neck by my shirt I added one row of rectangles from the neck to the torso by removing the neck seam and extending the shoulder seam.
Once I redo the UV mapping (unwrap), the UV map is messed up. Triangles overlap and exceed the map range.
[image: An example of a messed up mesh]
[Pictures before and after uv unwrapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSaPj.jpg)

- I doublechecked the seams, they are without any gap.
- I even added an additional, obviously not necessary seam at the neck end.
- I reseted the UV before.
- I removed the seams and reapply.
- I removed the seams and cut along shoulder and side like reat shirts.
- I removed all material from the mesh.

The result is the same, ot at least it's always a messed up UV map.

I'm quite sure I missed any simple step, an expert will shake it's head about.
All tutorials just apply the seams and get a perfect mesh immediately.
But I'm stuck and out of any idea to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Fiddeling around and examing a large number of related topics I found the solution by myself.

It seems the mesh is pinned (to whatever) and has to be freed before.

1. Select the mesh in edit mode
2. Go to UV mode/window and select all (A)
3. Unpin the mesh in UV mode (Alt P)
4. Redo the unwrap in UV mode (E)

Voila!

[image: Looks much better now]